# in node.js, how do I alter the response based on a request to a service?

Tags: node.js

I have a post form handler in Nodejs

```
function sendToSparkCore(request, response) {
    parseBody(request,function(body) {
        var post = {
            xx: body.switch_value
        }
        console.log(post.xx);
        rx.post(
            'https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/01234567/ledFn',
            { form: { 'access_token' : '987654321',
                'params' : post.xx } },
            function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(body);
                    // I want to sen output here
                } else {
                    console.log('Error encountered');
                    console.log(response.statusCode);
                    console.log(body);
                    // and here
                }
            }
        );
        response.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
        });
        response.end(newPostFormHTML);
    });
}
```

Is there a way to send output to the function's response object from the two commented lines 
i.e. on success or failure of the post?

Comment: So you're saying that you want to call `response.end` in the places that you've marked with comments?

Comment: response.end is what you need

Comment: unfortunately it is getting the wrong response object.

Comment: Nope = in the callback response refers to the wrong object. 
sendToSparkCore's version of response is out of scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you could just

```
return response.end(body);
```

in either of the if statements.

The problem with the above code is that you have response as a parameter to both your sendToSparkCore function and the callback for rx.post.  The rx.post response is clobbering the one from the outer scope, so that response is no longer your node response.  Just rename the inner response parameter.

Comment: Tried that.

/home/pi/spark/app.js:31
            return response.end(body);
                            ^
    TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'end'
        at Request._callback (/home/pi/spark/app.js:31:29)
        at Request.self.callback ........

Comment: Well it looks like your rx.post function redefines response in
  function (error, response, body). Name it as something else.

Comment: Thanks Robert.
I did try some time ago but I guess I was chasing too many other issues back then. Works now (I removed the other response.write/end)

If you make it an answer I can vote it up.